# checking if a array value is not empty without php warnings

Tags: php, zend-framework

I'm using `Zend_Form` subclasses to pass array of data to my controllers and sometimes I need some extra logic in the controllers, as such:

```
$post = $request->getPost();
if (array_key_exists('signatureData', $post) && !empty($post['signatureData'])) {
   ...
}
```

To avoid getting php warnings, first, I need to check if the `signatureData` key exists and only then I can check if the value is not empty.

Anyway I can make this IF statement a little shorter without adding custom php function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using zf, use this

```
If ($request->getParam('signatureData', false))
```

Best practice IMO

Answer (score 6):

Accepted standard :

```
if (isset($post['signatureData']) && !empty($post['signatureData']))
```

Apparently, this is also possible :

```
if (!empty($post['signatureData']))
```

-edit-

If you're really lazy, there's a dirty way :

```
if (@$post['signatureData'])
```

I'd recommend against it though.

**As pointed out in the comments, don't actually use this. It's bad, bad, bad bad, bad. Really though, please don't ever use it. It's only here as a reference.**

Comment: isnt an empty check enough? if the key doesnt exist, an empty check will return true, and if the key does exist but contains no value, empty will also return true.

Comment: @Julien - It is not enough, as it will raise a notice of an undefined index if `$post['signatureData']` is not set. I would also remove "the dirty way" as a possibility, as its a poor technique to create a habit out of.

Comment: It will also give a `Notice:` warning about checking an undefined index.

Comment: if the key doesn't exist, an empty check will return true and NOT raise a notice. From the PHP docs: "empty() is the opposite of (boolean) var, except that no warning is generated when the variable is not set."

Comment: Hmm, interesting - didn't know that, and I've never seen it used like that in code. Will update my answer :-)

Comment: yeah, i don't like the @ suppression as well, and we avoid using it as a part of our coding standard.